# A host module extended with ConfigurableModuleClass causing a dependency problem

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to make a module that passes an object to my module's register() function. I've followed the documentation for creating a dynamic module by extending the ConfigurableModuleClass and passing the object to its static register() function. The service that this module has in its providers and exports array complains and throws the following error:

ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CloudStorageService (?). Please make sure that the argument CONFIGURABLE_MODULE_OPTIONS[83c5b10d8075198b74ada] at index [0] is available in the CloudStorageModule context

on @nestjs/core: 9.4.3

Not sure what I've missed here. Attaching snippets of my code:

[image: relevant code snippets for app.module.ts, cloud-storage.module.ts, cloud-storage.module-definition.ts, cloud-storage.service.ts]

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, you're adding `CloudStorageModule` to an `imports` array without adding the `.register()`/`.registerAsync()` which will cause this error. In the module *without* that call, the only provider that exists is the `CloudStorageService`, but that provider depends on the options that come from the `CloudStorageModule.register()` dynamic module. If you want to not have to call the `.register` again, create a wrapper module that can use [module re-exporting](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#module-re-exporting) to configure and export the dynamic module

Comment: As it stands, I'm only importing CloudStorage module in my app.module.ts where I do call the .register() and pass the options. Not importing anywhere else in my code

Comment: Then a reproduction would be necessary, as that's generally what the error here would come from